# Serializing Json adds "InitializeTask":null element

Tags: c#, json

UPDATE:
It was caused by MvxViewModel. Changing to MvxNotifyPropertyChanged solved it (as it's actually all I want)!

When I sesrialise a Json to my type of CategoriesJson it adds a "InitializeTask":null element. 
So, my code of CategoriesJson :

```
public class CategoriesJson
{
    public CategoriesJson()
    {
        Categories = new List<CategoryViewModel>();
    }
    public List<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The CategoryViewModel is here:

```
public class CategoryViewModel : MvxViewModel
        , IHandle<CategorySelectedEvent>
        , IHandle<MainMonthChangedEvent>
    {
        private IEventAggregator events;
        private IConfigurationReader configurationReader;

        public CategoryViewModel()
        {
            Transfers = new List<Transfer>();
        }

        private MvxCommand addTransferClicked;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public IMvxCommand AddTransferClicked => addTransferClicked;

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Transfer> Transfers { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string TotalAmount => $"{GetTotalAmount()}";

        private Guid selectedMainMonthId;

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Guid SelectedMainMonthId
        {
            get => selectedMainMonthId;
            set
            {
                if (SetProperty(ref selectedMainMonthId, value))
                {
                    Transfers = configurationReader.ReadTransfers(Id, value);
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TotalAmount));
                }

            }
        }

        [JsonIgnore]
        private string transferAmount;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string TransferAmount
        {
            get => transferAmount;
            set => SetProperty(ref transferAmount, value);
        }

        [JsonIgnore]
        private bool isExpanded;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return isExpanded; }
            set => SetProperty(ref isExpanded, value);
        }

        //public List<MonthViewModel> Months => configurationReader.ReadMonths();
        [JsonIgnore]
        private MonthViewModel selectedMonth;

        [JsonIgnore]
        public MonthViewModel SelectedMonth
        {
            get { return selectedMonth; }
            set => SetProperty(ref selectedMonth, value);
        }

        public string GetTotalAmount()
        {
            double amount = 0;
            foreach (var transfer in Transfers)
            {
                amount += transfer.Amount;
            }

            return $"£ {amount}";
        }

        public void Handle(CategorySelectedEvent message)
        {
            if (Id != message.Id)
                return;

            IsExpanded = true;
        }

        private void AddTransfer()
        {
            var parsed = Double.TryParse(TransferAmount, out double amountResult);
            if (!parsed)
                return;

            configurationReader.AddTransfer(Id, amountResult, SelectedMonth.Id, DateTime.Now, "notes here");
            TransferAmount = String.Empty;
            IsExpanded = false;
        }

        public void Handle(MainMonthChangedEvent message)
        {
            SelectedMainMonthId = message.Id;
        }

        public override void ViewAppearing()
        {
            events = Mvx.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();

            events.Subscribe(this);
            configurationReader = Mvx.Resolve<IConfigurationReader>();
            Transfers = new List<Transfer>();
            addTransferClicked = new MvxCommand(AddTransfer);
            base.ViewAppearing();
        }
```

I put the JsonIgnore tag to all properties and fields that I don't want to serialize - this didn't help.
So, when I serialize Json, I get, for example:

```
{"Categories":[{"Id":"2d48427c-c170-4932-96e9-7668418ba008","Name":"test","Transfers":[],"InitializeTask":null}]}
```

I don't understand where that InitializeTask comes from.. It didn't before, but after I added some more code, it started to appear and I cannot trace to the earlier versions of my code to see what caused it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can be from base class `MvxViewModel` ?

Comment: So... search your code base for the `InitializeTask` code and add a `JsonIgnore` attribute to it.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Exactly, thanks! The solution was to change MvxViewModel to MvxNotifyPropertyChanged and it's gone!

Comment: cool. close the post and mark it answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `MvxViewModel` base class have that property and is causing issue.